# How does one Display a Hyperlink in React Native App?

Tags: javascript, react-native

How do I display a hyperlink in a React Native app?

e.g.

```
<a href="https://google.com>Google</a>
```

Comment: Consider adding more tags like 'javascript' to get more attention from users. But do not over-generalize your posts by adding tags like 'coding', etc.

Comment: @MattC I would argue that adding 'javascript' is too general.

Answer (score 421, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<Text style={{color: 'blue'}}
      onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://google.com')}>
  Google
</Text>
```

using the `Linking` module that's bundled with React Native.

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: If you need a dynamic value, you can use something like `this.props.url` in place of `'http://google.com'` (no braces necessary)

Comment: @philipp  it's throwing me error m 'can't find variable Linking'

Comment: @devanshsadhotra do you have `import { Linking } from 'react-native';` in your document?

Comment: You can embed <Text> elements too so that the linked text can be a portion of the parent text: `<Text>Some paragraph <Text onPress=...>with a link</Text> inside</Text>`

Comment: LinkingIOS has been depreciated, use Linking.

Comment: use <touchableOpacity> just for a little animation when the text is clicked

Comment: Don't forget to check if url can be opened. const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);

Answer (score 34):

The selected answer refers only to iOS. For both platforms, you can use the following component:

```js
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import {
  Linking,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

export default class HyperLink extends Component {

  constructor(){
      super();
      this._goToURL = this._goToURL.bind(this);
  }

  static propTypes = {
    url: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }

  render() {

    const { title} = this.props;

    return(
      <Text style={styles.title} onPress={this._goToURL}>
        >  {title}
      </Text>
    );
  }

  _goToURL() {
    const { url } = this.props;
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then(supported => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(this.props.url);
      } else {
        console.log('Don\'t know how to open URI: ' + this.props.url);
      }
    });
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  title: {
    color: '#acacac',
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
});
```

Comment: The selected answer worked fine for me in Android (RN 35).

Comment: @JacobLauritzen well now it's the same after someone copied my answer :/ http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30540502/revisions

Comment: Not in all cases suppoted === true, but link is valid. This is my approach to open link for both platfom https://stackoverflow.com/a/69089232/8602069

Answer (score 34):

To do this, I would strongly consider wrapping a `Text` component in a `TouchableOpacity`.  When a `TouchableOpacity` is touched, it fades (becomes less opaque).  This gives the user immediate feedback when touching the text and provides for an improved user experience.

You can use the `onPress` property on the `TouchableOpacity` to make the link happen:

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://google.com')}>
  <Text style={{color: 'blue'}}>
    Google
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 22):

#### React Native documentation suggests using `Linking`:

[Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.57/linking#opening-external-links)

#### Here is a very basic use case:

```
import { Linking } from 'react-native';

const url="https://google.com"

<Text onPress={() => Linking.openURL(url)}>
    {url}
</Text>
```

#### You can use either functional or class component notation, dealers choice.

Comment: LinkingIOS has been depreciated, use Linking.

Answer (score 11):

Another helpful note to add to the above responses is to add some flexbox styling.
This will keep the text on one line and will make sure the text doesn't overlap the screen.

```
 <View style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row", flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap', margin: 10 }}>
  <Text>Add your </Text>
  <TouchableOpacity>
    <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }} onpress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com')} >
         link
    </Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
   <Text>here.
   </Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to implement a hyperlink that appears underlined and has the web-standard behavior of changing colors when clicked (like CSS `a:active`).

```
import { Linking, Pressable, Text } from 'react-native';

  <Pressable onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://example.com')}>
    {({ pressed }) =>
      <Text style={{
        textDecorationLine: 'underline',
        color: pressed ? 'red' : 'blue'
      }}>I'm a hyperlink!</Text>
    }
  </Pressable>
```

- Some of the existing answers use `Text` and `Linking` with `TouchableOpacity`, but the [docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchableopacity) state that `Pressable` is more "future-proof" than `TouchableOpacity`, so we use `Pressable` instead.
- `Text` itself actually has an `onPress()` property, so `TouchableOpacity` is unnecessary for simply handling the press. However, it doesn't seem possible to implement the color style change with `Text` only.

Answer (score 5):

Use React Native Hyperlink (Native `<A>` tag):

Install:

```
npm i react-native-a
```

import:

```
import A from 'react-native-a'
```

Usage:

1. `<A>Example.com</A>`
2. `<A href="example.com">Example</A>`
3. `<A href="https://example.com">Example</A>`
4. `<A href="example.com" style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Example</A>`

Answer (score 3):

for the React Native, there is library to open Hyperlinks in App.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hyperlink

In addition to this, i suppose you will need to check url and best approach is Regex.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-regex

Comment: If you are building for ios, the SVC is better approach to implement rather than Linking (to open in Safari Browser).
https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-safari-view

Comment: Thanks for sharing https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hyperlink. Do not trouble yourself with all that self written stuff when you can just go for <HyperLink linkDefault={true} linkStyle={{ color: "#2980b9" }}> {//text mixed with links} /<HyperLink>

Answer (score 3):

Just thought I'd share my hacky solution with anyone who's discovering this problem now with *embedded links* within a string. It attempts to **inline the links** by rendering it dynamically with what ever string is fed into it.

Please feel free to tweak it to your needs. It's working for our purposes as such:

This is an example of how https://google.com would appear.

**View it on Gist:**

https://gist.github.com/Friendly-Robot/b4fa8501238b1118caaa908b08eb49e2

```
import React from 'react';
import { Linking, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function renderHyperlinkedText(string, baseStyles = {}, linkStyles = {}, openLink) {
  if (typeof string !== 'string') return null;
  const httpRegex = /http/g;
  const wwwRegex = /www/g;
  const comRegex = /.com/g;
  const httpType = httpRegex.test(string);
  const wwwType = wwwRegex.test(string);
  const comIndices = getMatchedIndices(comRegex, string);
  if ((httpType || wwwType) && comIndices.length) {
    // Reset these regex indices because `comRegex` throws it off at its completion. 
    httpRegex.lastIndex = 0;
    wwwRegex.lastIndex = 0;
    const httpIndices = httpType ? 
      getMatchedIndices(httpRegex, string) : getMatchedIndices(wwwRegex, string);
    if (httpIndices.length === comIndices.length) {
      const result = [];
      let noLinkString = string.substring(0, httpIndices[0] || string.length);
      result.push(<Text key={noLinkString} style={baseStyles}>{ noLinkString }</Text>);
      for (let i = 0; i < httpIndices.length; i += 1) {
        const linkString = string.substring(httpIndices[i], comIndices[i] + 4);
        result.push(
          <Text
            key={linkString}
            style={[baseStyles, linkStyles]}
            onPress={openLink ? () => openLink(linkString) : () => Linking.openURL(linkString)}
          >
            { linkString }
          </Text>
        );
        noLinkString = string.substring(comIndices[i] + 4, httpIndices[i + 1] || string.length);
        if (noLinkString) {
          result.push(
            <Text key={noLinkString} style={baseStyles}>
              { noLinkString }
            </Text>
          );
        }
      }
      // Make sure the parent `<View>` container has a style of `flexWrap: 'wrap'`
      return result;
    }
  }
  return <Text style={baseStyles}>{ string }</Text>;
}

function getMatchedIndices(regex, text) {
  const result = [];
  let match;
  do {
    match = regex.exec(text);
    if (match) result.push(match.index);
  } while (match);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Import Linking the module from React Native**

```
import { TouchableOpacity, Linking } from "react-native";
```

**Try it:-**

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://Facebook.com')}>
     <Text> Facebook </Text>     
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

The Below code uses **'Linking'** which is used as a anchor tag for mobile in React Native. This will make your text look like a hyperlink.

**'openURL'** is a function used from Linking used to open the desired url which is passed into its parameter.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>Linking.openURL('http://yahoo.com')}>
<Text style={{textDecorationLine:'underline',color:'blue}}>https://google.com</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do links and other types of rich text, a more comprehensive solution is to use [React Native HTMLView](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13192218)

Comment: @Ari0nhh I undeleted the question as it was the only way I could respond to your comment. There's lots of precedents on SO where a highly ranked answer is simply a link to a good library. Plus other answers already cover a simple implementation. I suppose I could repost this as a comment on the original question, but I do view it as a real answer. And leaving the link here is at least a crumb for future seekers, if people want to edit it and improve it with better examples at least now there's a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use linking property
<Text style={{color: 'skyblue'}}
onPress={() => Linking.openURL('http://yahoo.com')}>
Yahoo

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the following to align the touchable substring with the surrounding text. The fixed margin numbers are a bit hacky, but good enough if you don't need to use this with more than one font size. Otherwise you can pass the margins in as a prop along with the `BaseText` component.

```
import styled, { StyledComponent } from 'styled-components'
import { View, Linking, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

type StyledTextComponent = StyledComponent<typeof Text, any, {}, never>

export interface TouchableSubstringProps {
  prefix: string
  substring: string
  suffix: string
  BaseText: StyledTextComponent
  onPress: () => void
}

export const TouchableSubstring = ({
  prefix,
  substring,
  suffix,
  BaseText,
  onPress,
}: TouchableSubstringProps): JSX.Element => {
  const UnderlinedText = styled(BaseText)`
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: blue;
  `

  return (
    <TextContainer>
      <Text>
        <BaseText>{prefix}</BaseText>
        <TextAlignedTouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
          <UnderlinedText>{substring}</UnderlinedText>
        </TextAlignedTouchableOpacity>
        <BaseText>{suffix}</BaseText>
      </Text>
    </TextContainer>
  )
}

const TextContainer = styled(View)`
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 10px;
`

const TextAlignedTouchableOpacity = styled(TouchableOpacity)`
  margin-top: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Text, Linking } from 'react-native';

const MyLink = () => {
  const handlePress = () => {
    Linking.openURL('https://google.com');
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handlePress}>
      <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>Google</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default MyLink;
```