# How to open a facebook, instagram.. (social network) profile from my app

Tags: react-native

I'm creating an application using react native and I need to allow user to open all the available social networks of another user.
I saw that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616348/react-native-open-facebook-page) and this [one](https://github.com/flyandi/react-native-openanything/issues/5), but they doesn't works for me.

 can anyone help

**EDIT**
I know how to create icons and call social networks'  **website**, however, what I want is to open a user profile in a social networks **app**
I remarked that for instagram, the user profile url, opens the app, howover for Fb, it opens the website,

Answer (score 0):

This following is used in my project. Its the contact US page of my react native app.

Works fine for me.

```html
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, Dimensions, View, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, Image, Linking, ScrollView, Platform } from 'react-native';
    import { Icon, Card, CardItem } from 'native-base';
    import Colors from '../config/Colors';
    import Dimens from '../config/Dimens';
    import { RNToasty } from 'react-native-toasty';
    import OneSignal from 'react-native-onesignal';
    import { getStatusBarHeight } from 'react-native-status-bar-height';
    import { colors } from 'react-native-elements';
    import { Header } from 'react-navigation';
    import HeaderBackground from '../components/HeaderBackground';
    
    var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    class SocialMedia extends Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }
    
        static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                header: (props) => <HeaderBackground {...props} />,
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    paddingTop: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : getStatusBarHeight(),
                    height: Header.HEIGHT + (Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : getStatusBarHeight()),
                },
                title: 'Social Media',
                headerTintColor: Colors.white,
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    padding: 5,
                    paddingTop: 10
                },
                headerMode: 'float',
                headerLeft: <Icon
                    onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
                    name="arrow-back"
                    type='MaterialIcons'
                    style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: 10, padding: 5, paddingTop: 10 }}
                />,
            }
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(Colors.secondaryColor, false)} onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('https://www.facebook.com/max/') }}>
                            <Card style={styles.card}>
                                <CardItem style={styles.cardBody}>
                                    <Image source={require('../assets/icons/Contact_Facebook.jpg')} style={styles.icon} resizeMode='contain' />
                                    <Text style={styles.iconText}>Facebook</Text>
                                </CardItem>
                            </Card>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
    
                        <TouchableOpacity background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(Colors.secondaryColor, false)} onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('https://www.instagram.com/max/') }}>
                            <Card style={styles.card}>
                                <CardItem style={styles.cardBody}>
                                    <Image source={require('../assets/icons/Contact_Insta.jpg')} style={styles.icon} resizeMode='contain' />
                                    <Text style={styles.iconText}>Instagram</Text>
                                </CardItem>
                            </Card>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
    
                        <TouchableOpacity background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(Colors.secondaryColor, false)} onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnQoipGmBRC1XTOUY8c1UdA') }}>
                            <Card style={styles.card}>
                                <CardItem style={styles.cardBody}>
                                    <Image source={require('../assets/icons/Contact_YT.jpg')} style={styles.icon} resizeMode='contain' />
                                    <Text style={styles.iconText}>YouTube</Text>
                                </CardItem>
                            </Card>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
    
                        <TouchableOpacity background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple(Colors.secondaryColor, false)} onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('https://max.com/') }}>
                            <Card style={styles.card}>
                                <CardItem style={styles.cardBody}>
                                    <Image source={require('../assets/icons/Contact_web.jpg')} style={styles.icon} resizeMode='contain' />
                                    <Text style={styles.iconText}>Website</Text>
                                </CardItem>
                            </Card>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
    
                    </View>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            flex: 1,
            padding: 8
        },
        contentContainer: {
            paddingBottom: 20
        },
        cardContainer: {
            flex: 1,
            padding: 5,
            width: '100%',
        },
        card: {
            padding: 5,
            height: height * .20,
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: '#fff',
            flexDirection: 'column',
            //alignItems: 'center',
            //justifyContent: 'center',
            shadowColor: '#1A9EAEFF',
            shadowOffset: { width: 3, height: 3 },
            shadowOpacity: 3,
            shadowRadius: 2,
            elevation: 10,
            borderRadius: 5,
            overflow: 'hidden'
        },
        cardBody: {
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'row',
        },
        iconText: {
            flex: 1,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            fontSize: 18,
            color: '#1A9EAEFF'
        },
        icon: {
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
            height: width * .18,
        },
    });
    
    
    export default SocialMedia;
```

Hope this helps..

You're good to go!!

Comment: thank you for your response, but I want to open the social network apps,  with the URL passed to the Linking, it will open it in a browser

Comment: for exemple for facebook : Linking.openURL("fb://...."); will open the fb app, but I dont know how to choose the user profile to be open

Answer (score 0):

For instagram this is working for me,

```
Linking.openURL('https://www.instagram.com/profile_username/');
```

for facebook its just opening the facebook app.

```
Linking.openURL('fb://profile_username/');
```