# Facebook Deep linking in React Native

Tags: react-native, facebook

hope things going well on your side.
I'm displaying all post of a Facebook page on my app, and now, when I click on it, it should open Facebook app in post detail screen. 
Is that possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46616404/7230188

Comment: This isn't what I'm asking. Its talk about deeplink to profile while mine is deep linking to post detail