# Show Hyperlinks in React Native Alert?

Tags: react-native, hyperlink, alert

I want to use the Alert Api to display OS behavior alerts.
I'm asking myself if you can display Hyperlinks inside the Text of an alert?

```
Alert.alert(
    'Alert', 
    'This is an Alert. I want to include hyperlinks here.',
    [
        {
            text: 'Cancel', 
            onPress: () => console.log("Alert cancel"),
            style: 'cancel',
        },
        {
            text: 'Accept', 
            onPress: () => console.log("Alert accept"),
            style: 'default'
        },
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a [dialog container](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dialog), and use the React Native Linking component on the Dialog.Description onPress() to turn it into a hyperlink:

```
<Dialog.Description onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com')} 
    style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: 'blue' }}>www.google.com</Dialog.Description>
```

or you could add a Text component inside the Dialog.Description alongside some other text to just have a certain word be the hyperlink:

```
<Dialog.Description>
    Visit this website:
    <Text onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://www.google.com')}
        style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline', color: 'blue' }}>www.google.com</Text>
</Dialog.Description>
```

---

*A word of caution, you're suppose to only pass a string to the Dialog.Description and doing the above will give you a console warning. So use at your own caution but it's working fine for me, and you can hide the warning using the React Native YellowBox component by adding this line outside of your class export (so near the import statements):*

```
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Failed prop type: Invalid prop `children` of type `array` supplied to `DialogDescription`, expected `string`'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Much better to create a Modal (or simply a View component with position: absolute) to handle this than to dive into the native code.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.56/modal

Comment: Yes this was the solution in the production app. It behaves really well and it is looking good with rounded borders.

Comment: updated modal link: [https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/modal#example). By the way, this should be marked as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install "react-native-dialogs"( an android only module for material design dialogs) as follows:

1] Installation:

```
npm install react-native-dialogs --save
```

2] Linking:

```
react-native link react-native-dialogs
```

3] Import it in your page:

```
import DialogAndroid from 'react-native-dialogs';
```

also need to add below code inside your render:

```
<Button title="show custom alert" onPress={this.showCustomAlert} />
```

and at last add below function in your screen:

```
showCustomAlert() {
   DialogAndroid.alert('Alert', `This is a link <a 
     href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>`, {
    contentIsHtml: true
   });
}
```

You can find more details here https://github.com/aakashns/react-native-dialogs

Answer (score -1):

This is possible using the Linking module that comes with React-Native. Please check out the following:

[Display hyperlink in React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540252/display-hyperlink-in-react-native-app)

If this doesn't work maybe try this npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-hyperlink

Comment: @realarb If this answers your question please mark it as the correct answer! Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not because the params for Alert.alert accepts only strings for the descriptions. I think there is no solution to display a native Alert IOS with hyperlinks inside.

Comment: @realarb i edited my answer there. Maybe that npm package might help

Comment: No the Method from Alert accepts only pure strings. You can't nest React Components. I want the user to accept the privacy policy using the Alert and link the privacy policy inside the Alert.

Comment: This could be solved if I would write the Alert Box native in Objective-C combining it with React Native. But for that I have to get more knowledge.