# display a Link button instead of button

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to display a link button instead of button on my react native page. Right now I have the below code:

```
<Button onPress={this.handleGetDirections} title="Get Directions" />
```

I want to show the above button as a link. How can I achieve this in React Native.

Thank You.

Comment: Like a hyperlink?

Comment: bootstrap button css the link, problem solve?

Comment: @Se0ng11 React **Native**.

Comment: something like this? check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540252/display-hyperlink-in-react-native-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display hyperlink in React Native App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540252/display-hyperlink-in-react-native-app)

Comment: I don't have a url. I just wantto go to certain page that exists in my application when user clicks on that directions link

Comment: Hii, try this
https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-hyperlink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `textDecorationLine`.

E.g :

```
 <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.underLineText}>Your underline Text</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>

underLineText: {
    fontSize: 12,
    textDecorationLine: 'underline',
    color: 'white',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
```

Comment: This works perfect, thanks! For anyone not aware, `TouchableOpacity` can be imported from `react-native`.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about the styling of a link within the browser. That's done by the default browser vendor styles. You won't have that happen in react-native.

You can have a simple `Text` element that is styled to look like a link (ie: blue) and have a `onPress` handler for that.

Just follow Pritish Vaidyas... link :)

Hope this helps