# Link within the same page in react native

Tags: react-native

Hello guys im trying to find a react-native code which is equivalent to the html code below:

```
   <a href="#Ducks">Ducks Section</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p name="Ducks">this is about ducks</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping a Text component in a TouchableOpacity.

```
class App extends Component {
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity>
          <Text style={{color: 'blue'}} onPress={() => {}}>
             Ducks Section
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        
        <TouchableOpacity style={{marginTop:50}}> <!-- According to you requirement-->
          <Text style={{color: 'blue'}} onPress={() => {}}>
             this is about ducks
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      
      <View>
    );
  }
}
```

You can use a [react-native-hyperlink](https://github.com/obipawan/react-native-hyperlink#readme) component for react-native-web that makes urls, fuzzy links, emails etc clickable. More discussion found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540252/how-does-one-display-a-hyperlink-in-react-native-app)

Comment: i just want to scroll down to specific section when links clicked not to redirect to other web links